# Lie algebra cohomology with values in the ring of smooth functions of a $G$-manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-algebra-cohomology

Let $G$ be a connected Lie group with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ acting faithfully on a smooth, finite-dimensional manifold $M$.  Let $C^\infty(M)$ and $\mathcal{X}(M)$ denote the ring of smooth functions and the smooth vector fields on $M$, respectively.

The group action defines a Lie algebra homomorphism $\mathfrak{g} \to \mathcal{X}(M)$ sending $X \in \mathfrak{g}$ to the vector field $\zeta_X$.  This turns $C^\infty(M)$ into a $\mathfrak{g}$-module, with action $f \mapsto \zeta_X f$.

I am interested in the first cohomology $H^1(\mathfrak{g};C^\infty(M))$.  These are equivalence classes of cocycles; that is, linear maps $h: \mathfrak{g} \to C^\infty(M)$ satisfying
$$
\zeta_X h(Y) - \zeta_Y h(X) = h([X,Y])
$$
for all $X,Y \in \mathfrak{g}$, where two cocycles $h_1$ and $h_2$ are equivalent if there exists some $f \in C^\infty(M)$ such that
$$
h_1(X) - h_2(X) = \zeta_X f
$$
for all $X \in \mathfrak{g}$.  These are the standard definitions, but I record them here for completeness and in case people have seen these conditions in a non-cohomological context.

My main **question** is whether there are any results on $H^1(\mathfrak{g};C^\infty(M))$.  For example, is it still the case that if $\mathfrak{g}$ is semisimple, the cohomology is $0$?  (This would be the case for finite-dimensional modules.)

Although I am working in a fairly general context and do not have any $\mathfrak{g}$ or $M$ in mind, I would be interested in any results, even if for particular $\mathfrak{g}$ and $M$, that may illustrate techniques to compute the cohomology.

An interesting geometric avatar of this cohomology group (and the source of my question) is when $M$ is a co-oriented contact manifold and $G$ acts preserving the contact structure.  The cohomology group in question houses the obstruction to the existence of an invariant contact one-form.

Comment: Your cocycles are just smooth maps? They are usually *linear*.

Comment: You're right, of course.  I meant to write "linear" :)

Comment: The original version looked intriguing :-)